# Uncountable set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ such that every $d$ vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I was just browsing through MSE and found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257479/there-exist-an-infinite-subset-s-subseteq-mathbbr3-such-that-any-three-vect) question. It is about finding an infinite set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for every three different vectors in $S$ are linearly independent.

Given the answer provided there, it is not hard to see that a similar result holds for any dimension $d\in \mathbb{N}$:
For all $d\in \mathbb{N}$, there is an infinite subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ such that all $X \in \binom{S}{d} = \{X \subseteq S \space | \space |X| = d\}$ are linearly independent.

Now my question is: can we even choose $S$ in such a way that $|S| = |\mathbb{R}|$?

A few ideas I have so far:

- For $d = 1$ we can just choose $S = \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.
- For $d=2$ we can choose $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \space | \space x,y > 0 \text{ and } x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$
  [image]
- For $d=3$ we can choose a suited curve on the sphere or on the plane defined by $z=1$, e.g. $S = \{ (x,x^2,1) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \space | \space x \in \mathbb{R} \}$
  [image]
- For $d \geq 4$, I have no idea. Maybe again some curve?

I accept any proof or disproof, however I would prefer an explicit example.

Comment: The answer you linked also answers your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extrapolate [Hagen von Eitzen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/257491/1508) to your linked question: the vectors $(1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^{n-1})$ are linearly independent, because the determinant of the corresponding [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is non-zero when all the rows are different.